# Espaço em branco indesejado entre header e section

Tags: html, css

Por que o css cria esse espaço em branco entre o header e a section, se estou aplicando margin-top apenas na div"card-container" dentro da section?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;

  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 85px;

  background-color: gray;

  
}

header h1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  
}


.cards {
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;

  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <h1>Teste</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Images</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="cards">Texto 1</div>
        <div class="cards">Texto 2</div>
        <div class="cards">Texto 3</div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: o problema é a `margen` na classe "card-container", tenta remover ou ajustar isso. não relativo ao problema mas não deu pra deixar de notar, "Testo" é um *typo* certo? :)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você coloca dois valores somente, o primeiro valor vale para o eixo Y ou seja top e bottom. Já o segundo valor vale para o eixo X, ou seja, right e left.

Ao colocar -> 15px auto;

Você está definindo 15px tanto para o top quanto para o bottom, da mesma forma o auto para right e left.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).